# The Hilbert epsilon operator

Tags: operator-keyword, dafny, epsilon

Why you can use the Hilbert epsilon operator in a method and in a function, but not in a "function method"?

```css
method choose<T>(s:set<T>) returns (x:T)
 requires s != {}
{
var z :| z in s;
return z;
}

function choose'<T>(s:set<T>):T
// function method choose'<T>(s:set<T>):T // Activate this line and comment the previous line to see the error
 requires s != {}
{
var z :| z in s;
z
}
```

Comment: You didn't say what actual error you found. Current Dafny (3.1.0) complains that "to be compilable, the value of a let-such-that expression must be uniquely determined".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for the Hilbert epsilon operator, also known in Dafny as the let-such-that expression,

```
var z :| P; E
```

to be compilable, the constraint `P` must determine `z` uniquely. In your case, the constraint `P` is `z in s`, which does not determine `z` uniquely except for singleton sets.

If `s` were of type `set<int>`, you can (inefficiently) live up to this requirement by changing your `choose'` function to:

```
function method choose'<T>(s:set<int>):int
  requires s != {}
{
  var z :| z in s && forall y :: y in s ==> z <= y;
  z
}
```

Almost. You need to convince Dafny there is such a `z`. You can do that in a lemma. Here's a probably-longer-than-necessary-but-the-first-thing-I-got-working lemma that does that. Note that the lemma also uses the Hilbert operator, but in a statement context, so the uniqueness requirement does not apply.

```
function method choose'<T>(s:set<int>):int
  requires s != {}
{
  HasMinimum(s);
  var z :| z in s && forall y :: y in s ==> z <= y;
  z
}

lemma HasMinimum(s: set<int>)
  requires s != {}
  ensures exists z :: z in s && forall y :: y in s ==> z <= y
{
  var z :| z in s;
  if s == {z} {
    // the mimimum of a singleton set is its only element
  } else if forall y :: y in s ==> z <= y {
    // we happened to pick the minimum of s
  } else {
    // s-{z} is a smaller, nonempty set and it has a minimum
    var s' := s - {z};
    HasMinimum(s');
    var z' :| z' in s' && forall y :: y in s' ==> z' <= y;
    // the minimum of s' is the same as the miminum of s
    forall y | y in s
      ensures z' <= y
    {
      if
      case y in s' =>
        assert z' <= y;  // because z' in minimum in s'
      case y == z =>
        var k :| k in s && k < z;  // because z is not minimum in s
        assert k in s';  // because k != z
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, the type of your `s` is not `set<int>`. I don't know how to get a unique value from a general set. :(

For information about why the uniqueness requirement is important in compiled expressions see [this paper](https://easychair.org/publications/open/dM).

Rustan

Comment: While this answer is very informative, it doesn't actually answer the question of why the problem happens only in a function method. My understanding is that the function can't cause a compilation error because it's never compiled. The method also doesn't cause an error because methods aren't required to return the same result when executed with the same input / state. But function methods are both compiled AND expected to always return the same output for a given input, which the let-such-that operator doesn't do by itself in Dafny (as detailed in the paper mentioned) so it needs contraining.